# Active listeners of subscription in azure service bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azureportal

I'm looking for some way to show a list of current listeners for each subscription in Azure service bus. Do you know some API/Azure SDK or may it's available from Azure portal to show that information? A language is not relevant

Comment: If you want to know what WorkerRoles (or Processes) are listening for messages in a Topic/Subscription there is no API able to do so, you only option will be to open an incident and let the Azure Service Bus escalation engineers to look trough the logs of your subscription to retrieve the IPs of the machines doing work against the subscription.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.Weird I can't make a list of subscribers :(